# Dropdown Button Didn't Showing

Tags: node.js, pug

I work with Jade (pug) and Nodejs.

I created a dropdown button, so that user can choose an item, but it didn't show in the application. There is no dropdown there. I've already use display:block and clean the browser cache. But still stuck here.

Here is my .pug file:

```
.filters-nav
  .btn-group.m-r-15
    button.btn.btn-inverse.dropdown-toggle.waves-effect.waves-light.btn-custom(type='button', data-toggle='dropdown', aria-expanded='false')
      span.btn-label
        i.fa.fa-filter
      | Add filters
      span.caret
    ul.dropdown-menu.filters-dropdown(role='menu')
      li
        a(href='#', data-filter='table_1_filter_0') Instrument ID
      li
        a(href='#', data-filter='table_1_filter_1') Instrument Code
```

I wonder if it is CSS, but all I know is CSS doesn't related to element visibility at all.

Comment: You can show and hide elements with CSS using the `display`, `visibility` or `opacity` property. Post your relevant CSS.

Comment: @Charlie Martin I've got so many CSS related to this .pug. Do you mean the CSS with same filename with this .pug?

Comment: Besides, which element I have to check in CSS, is it `filters-nav` or else?

Comment: you can use your browser's `developer tools` and `inspect element` feature to check whether this element is even being rendered in the html and if yes, then which css rule is causing it to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, its pug plus the css

```
 li.dropdown.btn.btn-default
  span.glyphicon.glyphicon-th-list
   ............
```

https://codepen.io/thehumanscience/pen/qbLepW